# how to use readEntries and implement it into a button in phonegap?

Tags: android, api, file, cordova

I have been reading the File API documentation of phonegap-2.9.0
and I believe readEntries() is the method I should use if I want to click a button and then right under the button it'll show all the files/directories.

I looked at the sample html

```
function success(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    console.log(entries[i].name);
    }
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("Failed to list directory contents: " + error.code);
}

// Get a directory reader
var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();

// Get a list of all the entries in the directory
directoryReader.readEntries(success,fail);
```

also found this code online

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 512000, function(fs) {fs.root.createReader().readEntries(function(entries){for(var I in entries)console.log(entries[I].name);})});
```

Somehow I'm not too sure how to use them and implement it into a button.
Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390299/file-api-phonegap